# Multiple different roles to a python class

Tags: python

What is the best way to apply multiple different "roles" to an object of a class.

Let's say I have the following classes

```
class BasicAccessSettings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.option_1 = True
        self.option_2 = True
        self.option_3 = False 
        self.option_4 = False
        self.option_5 = False
```

```
class SpecialAccessSettings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.option_1 = True
        self.option_2 = True
        self.option_3 = True
        self.option_4 = True
        self.option_5 = True
```

Then I would like to be able to make certain additional modifications to objects of those classes. For example, I could have multiple different settings that modify some of the options, such as something like: `SpecialRole1` that has options 1 and 2 set to False or `SpecialRole2` that has options 1 and 4 set to True.

Then if I apply `SpecialRole1` and `SpecialRole2` to `BasicAccessSettings` (in that order), the resulting settings would be

```
option_1 = True   # from SpecialRole2
option_2 = False  # from SpecialRole1
option_3 = False  # from BasicAccessSettings
option_4 = True   # from SpecialRole2
option_5 = False  # from BasicAccessSettings
```

Similarly, I would like to be able to add the same special roles to `SpecialAccessSettings` if needed. How could this be implemented?

I've considered decorators and inheritance, but wasn't really able to figure out the best way. Inheritance would result in a massive amount of different classes but maybe multiple inheritance could be the solution somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance works well here:

```
class Roles:
    def SpecialRole1(self):
        self.option_2 = False
        self.option_2 = False
        
    def SpecialRole2(self):
        self.option_1 = True
        self.option_4 = True

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Options: {self.option_2} {self.option_2} {self.option_3} {self.option_4} {self.option_5}"

 
class BasicAccessSettings(Roles):
    option_1 = True
    option_2 = True
    option_3 = False
    option_4 = False
    option_5 = False
  
class SpecialAccessSettings(Roles):
    option_1 = True
    option_2 = True
    option_3 = True
    option_4 = True
    option_5 = True
```

Then you can:

```
user1 = BasicAccessSettings()
user1.SpecialRole1()
user1.SpecialRole2()
print(user1)
```

Which will work as expected giving, the default basic plus the role modifications in order:

```
Options: True False False True False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
class BasicAccessSettings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.option_1 = True
        self.option_2 = True
        self.option_3 = False 
        self.option_4 = False
        self.option_5 = False

    def SpecialRole1(self):
        self.option_1 = False
        self.option_2 = False

    def SpecialRole2(self):
        self.option_1 = True
        self.option_4 = True

    def get_all_options(self):
        print(self.option_1)
        print(self.option_2)
        print(self.option_3)
        print(self.option_4)
        print(self.option_5)


        
obj = BasicAccessSettings()
obj.SpecialRole1()
obj.SpecialRole2()
obj.get_all_options()
```

output:

```
True
False
False
True
False
```

Comment: What if I want to give same special roles to the other `SpecialAccessSettings` as well. Using this approach, I would have to copy the exact same methods to the other class and I'd like to avoid writing duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage the permissions (options) in an `enum.IntFlag` and use it as follows

```py
from enum import IntFlag

class Permission(IntFlag):
    access = 2**0
    create = 2**1
    edit = 2**2
    delete = 2**3
    
    reader_role = access
    writer_role = access | create
    editor_role = access | create | edit | delete
    
    @classmethod
    def _all(cls):
        permission = 0
        for value in cls.__members__.values():
            permission |= value
        return permission

class User:
    # default permission
    permissions = Permission.reader_role
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def _with_permsiion(permission):
        def decorator(method):
            def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if not self.permissions & permission == permission:
                    raise PermissionError(f'User "{self.name}" is not allowed!')
                return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return decorator
    
    @_with_permsiion(Permission.delete)
    def delete_file(self, path):
        print(f'User "{self.name}" deletes {path}')
        
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.permissions == Permission._all()


admin = User("admin")
admin.permissions = Permission.editor_role
assert admin.is_admin()
admin.delete_file('path/to/file')
user1 = User("custom")
user1.permissions |= Permission.delete
user1.delete_file('path/to/file')
user2 = User("normal")
user2.delete_file('path/to/file')
```

Edit:
Give the permissions self-explanatory names and provide a decorator in the user class to check permission for specific methods.

Edit2: Had a bug in the permission check.

Comment: Interesting method, but are you actually using the fact of being your permissions powers of 2? Unix-like systems uses that so you can write your final permission as the sum of all the permissions you have.

Comment: Yes, the power of two is important because it basically goes down to the binary representation, where each flag corresponds to a bit in the integer. You check the bits with the and operator and join them with the or operator. If you also allow combinations (the roles) you should not just sum, but aggregate using the or which unfortunately does not have a build in like aggregation on plus (sum).

Comment: @PabloRuiz thanks for the comment, it made me find a bug :-)